# SQL SELECT multiple SUM for two tables

Tags: sqlite, sum, multiple-tables

I have two SQLite tables:

Workouts:

```
WorkoutID   WorkoutDate
1           25.01.2012
2           19.04.2012
```

WorkoutExercises:

```
ExerciseID   WorkoutID   Muscles    Exercise            Set1_Rep    Set1_W      Set2_Rep    Set2_W
1            1           Abdominals Crunches            20          72,00       22          72,00
2            1           Abdominals Decline Crunch      25          72,00       25          72,00
3            1           Chest      Decline Push-Up     12          50,00       10          55,00
4            1           Chest      Chain Press         10          55,00       10          60,00
5            1           Chest      Machine Bench Press 14          45,00       12          50,00
6            2           Biceps     Drag Curl           18          35,00       16          40,00
7            2           Biceps     Hammer Curls        10          60,00       10          65,00
8            2           Biceps     Preacher Curl       12          35,00       12          40,00
9            2           Biceps     Spider Curl         11          50,00       10          50,00
10           2           Neck       Chin To Chest Stretch   20      72,00       20          72,00
```

I want to display for every `WorkoutDate` and `Muscles`, total number of exercises, total number of reps and total weight, like this:

```
25.01.2012
Abdominals: 2 exercises
92 reps, 288 lbs
Chest: 3 exercises
68 reps, 315 lbs

19.04.2012
Biceps: 4 exercises
99 reps, 375 lbs
Neck: 1 exercise
40 reps, 144 lbs
```

I got as far as getting the sum of reps and weight for every muscle group:

```
SELECT Muscles, 
SUM(Set1_Rep)+SUM(Set2_Rep)+SUM(Set3_Rep)+SUM(Set4_Rep)+SUM(Set5_Rep) AS [Reps], SUM(Set1_W)+SUM(Set2_W)+SUM(Set3_W)+SUM(Set4_W)+SUM(Set5_W) AS [Weight] 
FROM WorkoutExercises
GROUP BY Muscles
```

How do I count the number of exercises (Exercise) for every muscle group (Muscles) for every day (WorkoutDate)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: I got as far as getting the sum of reps and weight for every muscle group:
SELECT Muscles, 
    SUM(Set1_Rep)+SUM(Set2_Rep)+SUM(Set3_Rep)+SUM(Set4_Rep)+SUM(Set5_Rep) AS [Reps], SUM(Set1_W)+SUM(Set2_W)+SUM(Set3_W)+SUM(Set4_W)+SUM(Set5_W) AS [Weight] 
    FROM WorkoutExercises
    GROUP BY Muscles

Comment: How do I count the number of exercises (Exercise) for every muscle group (Muscles) for every day (WorkoutDate)?